# tinymce saves f.e paragraph with inserted text as html, and that renders back as escaped html tag on load from sqlite db in textarea form

Tags: python-3.x, flask, tinymce, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Input form in Flask, WTForms, SQLite, TinyMCE.
The textarea is replaced by TinyMCE, text entered f.e as paragraph, input saved into SQLite db.

When the entered data is displayed on a page, it renders as `<p>Text entered</p>` instead of just `Text entered`

I've tried setting `{{ wtf.quick_form(form)|save }}` so the content isn't escaped, and `verify_html: false,` in the TinyMCE script, but to no avail..

Is there any way to make it so that the entered text is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Again, nevermind! I was adding the `|save` parameter to the wrong function..

What I needed to do was to add to the function that displays the entered text, not on the form generator...

What I did: `{{ post.text|safe }}`